# Is this problem from Salesforce side or eclipse side and how to solve it

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, exception, eclipse

Working with Schedulable class and make some changes in reference class which will be called when Schedule run.I have corrected all reference so there are no *`variable does not exist`*  *type* issues but throwing an unexpected error on save.

```
Error: Problem with the existing metadata for this class, try deleting the class first or contact support
```

I don't want to delete class, it is part of managed package. How to remove this error, why does this happen and is it from eclipse or Salesforce side?

Comment: Is it still scheduled while you try to edit it ? I believe you may need to first abort/cancel scheduled jobs.

Comment: No, I deleted all schedule jobs before edit/save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Eclipse error. It can happen sometimes when the metadata is out of sync with the server (i.e. it is a bug). You can generally resolve this by refreshing the entire project from the server (Force.com > Refresh from server), then restoring the class' contents from local history, then re-building the project. If this fails, you'll have to delete the entire 'src' folder (choose 'no' when asked to delete from server), re-creating the 'src' folder, and finally refreshing from server.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, but I corrected it without deleting any class/component.